# SyndicationFeed.Load fails for specific feed

Tags: .net, feed

My code for reading feed from a url is like below,

```
var reader = XmlReader.Create("http://stackoverflow.com/feeds");
var feed = SyndicationFeed.Load(reader);
```

This works fine. But when I wanted to load some other feed like

```
"http://www.microsoft.com/feeds/technet/en-us/TechNetNewsFeed.xml".
```

It fails with exception

```
'Text' is an invalid XmlNodeType. Line 18, position 1002.
```

What I understood from the searching and reading different questions and answers, it seems a problem with rss/atom version of the feed I am trying to read.

How can I resolve it? Also It would be better if the solution works for all (well almost) feed types and without using any external library. If that is not possible please suggest some lightweight open source external library.

Comment: It's right. There's something broken in that feed - the letter `i` (some text) appears between two `<item>` entries. It doesn't work with broken feeds

Comment: Thanks. I tried locally by removing the 'i' and it works.

Comment: BTW is there anything I can do to parse it? I used Linq and it worked but the code becomes too big for manually parse each properties.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

@Damien_The_Unbeliever's comment is right. The feed xaml was wrong. That answers my question.